# Returning five minimum integers from a vector consists of twenty integers in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I would like to return five minimum integers from a vector consists of twenty integers in MATLAB. Any help? Thanks.

**Example:**

```
X = [6 7 8 3 5 6 7 2 5 1 0 6 6 2 9 6 3 3 4 77];
```

How to get the five minimum values from this vector?

Comment: Unique integers or not? If the latter, you can simply sort and slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Sort](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html?refresh=true) function and then take the 5 in the end of the array

```
sorted_x = sort(X)

5Minimum = sorted_x(15:20)
```

Comment: Also, the OP asked for 5 not six and minimum not maximum. you could use `sort(X, descend)` in first line or `sorted_x(1:5)` in the second line.